# Can a Minor Carry a Knife in Kansas?

Tags: minor, weapons, kansas

I'm 13, and I am wondering if it would be legal to carry a karambit knife for self defense – in a sheath or folded? If laws for both are different, I would appreciate policies on both. If so, would I be allowed to conceal it? Or would it have to be in plain sight? Any specific blade length limits?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: You might review Kansas knife laws [here](http://www.knifeup.com/kansas-knife-laws/).  I don't think I've seen knife laws that stipulate age requirements.  (But that doesn't mean there aren't more general laws pertaining to minors and weapons....)

Comment: This type of knife is explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karambit

Comment: I would note that *where* you carry the knife is relevant. Almost every school district and private school, as well as many recreation centers and clubs and malls, would prohibit carrying knives for self-defense purposes and often would have very stiff penalties (e.g. zero tolerance expulsion from school) for doing so. And, police may feel justified in shooting you if you are carrying a knife. So, there is not one answer for all times and places. There are also many local ordinances as well as state laws on this topic, again implicating the *where* issue.

Comment: Why would you carry a knife like that? Wouldn't it make much more sense if you just carried a pocket knife?

Comment: In the UK, if you are carrying a knife for self defense, that is evidence that you were willing and prepared to use it. So if you use it against a person, this will very, very much be held against you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knife laws in the United States are notoriously ambiguous, often vary at the municipality level, and enforcement can best be described as *capricious*.  I can't put it better than [this eye-opening answer I found on Quora](https://www.quora.com/I-have-a-6-5-dagger-that-I-carry-on-me-in-a-belt-patch-for-self-protection-Is-this-illegal/answer/Michael-DeBusk?srid=hZFA):

> Don't ask anybody what the law is about knives. Not even the police.
>   There's so much misinformation floating around out there.
>
> ...
>
> Check the law yourself. Not just state law, but local law for any
>   county or city you stop in or pass through.
>
> I was tasked with writing a weapons policy for my security department,
>   my former employer. I checked the Code of Maryland Regulations and
>   found a mess. Knives are considered tools, not weapons, unless and
>   until one uses or intends to use a knife as a weapon; knives are legal
>   regardless of blade length; folding knives may be carried concealed,
>   but fixed knives must be carried open; switchblades and balisongs are
>   not OK, but no mention of gravity knives, locking mechanisms, or
>   assisted-open mechanisms.
>
> I carried my S&W assisted-open knife everywhere, including into
>   Baltimore City several times. Then Freddie Gray was arrested for
>   carrying one and died in custody. A whole lot of people thought the
>   arresting officer had made an unlawful arrest, based on the state law,
>   *including the Baltimore City prosecutor* … until someone bothered to
>   check the city law and found that assisted-open knives are *illegal in
>   Baltimore City*. The arrest was a good one. And I left my knife in my
>   car from then on whenever I went into that town.

(I have on occasion asked police about knife laws.  In *every case* the officer has declined to answer whether a particular knife or carry practice was legal.)